# Fotorama - how to generate thumbnails when using CSS Sprites?

Tags: html, css-sprites, fotorama

I'm using http://fotorama.io/ to make a slideshow and it's increasing my page load time due to # of imgs.

Fotorama can auto-generate thumbnails from your images. To help load speed I combined the images into a CSS sprite. It seems to need an "img" tag to generate the thumbnail.

Any ideas on how to get it to display the thumbs when the "img" tag is not used?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit old the question but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3Uz9/3/) is a fiddle that uses `<div style='background: url()'>` as thumbs. It doesn't use *sprites*, but if you know how to do sprites, thats an easy step. Just add `.thumbs a div { background: url(myimage.jpg);}` to your CSS and `background-position:-30px -150px;` and so on to every div.

The code is copied from the [custom-thumbs](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/blob/master/test/custom-thumbs.html) example and only the css is changed to style the `div` instead of an `img`.

BTW: Thanks for introducing me to fotorama, thats basically the gallery I was just coding. Except for the css-sprites.

If you need any help with the sprites, I made a small js-library and shellscript to autogenerate the sprites and code for an image folder.

Comment: I am needing to use sprites it seems as i have a page with 150 images or so. Its causing me to have a horrible page load time. Could you please point me in the right direction on how i could solve this? I have to display all the images.

Comment: Are the images just thumbnails or bigger? Thumbnails can be combined into one bigger image containing all images and then addressed with CSS `background-position`. This greatly reduces the request overhead. If they are full-size images, there is not much you can do, besides stuffing tem into an i-frame only video and use a video player to display them. Are you even using Fotorama? You probably should open a new question (and maybe give me a ping about it).